# Neo4j GraphSage gds.beta.graphSage.train uses only 4 cores although more available cores exists

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I am working on Neo4j graph embeddings. When I try to create embeddings using graphsage algorithm, the process takes a too long time. I see 4 parallel processes working with 100% CPU usage from htop result. Is there a way to use more cores? (I have 48 available cores). Also, I use community edition. And, my Cypher query is shown as below;

```
CALL gds.beta.graphSage.train(
  'xxx',
  {
    modelName: 'xxx',
    featureProperties: ['yyy', 'zzz'],
    projectedFeatureDimension: 4
  }
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Community edition of GDS only supports 4 cores. If you want to use more than 4 cores, you will need to purchase the enterprise GDS license.